# Massive Computational Power from a PC Ecosystem

Tags: linux, parallel-processing, hpc

I am investigating how to build a laptop ecosystem to combine computational power. This is very similar to an HPC, but conceptually different.

I want to be able to combine processors and memory from computers that are interconnected, maybe over a LAN or internet. The idea is that users might be willing to contribute computational power as a free service (just like users contribute seeds on torrents). So that I can launch a job, and the job is distributed among the contributed resources. Users should be able to join or leave the ecosystem as they choose.

I have investigated the following:

Typical cluster software like Rocks: I don't want to compel users to install an operating system.

[Openmosix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenMosix): very close to what I want, but support has stopped. The project [LinuxPMI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LinuxPMI) seems to be closer, but development is slow and documentation is scarce. I'm experimenting this anyway and I'll post my findings soon. I'll like to know your experience with this.

OpenSSI/Kerrighed: not very satisfactory to me for now.

Please let me know your thoughts if there are any existing open-source projects to consider.

Comment: LinuxPMI is the successor of openMosix as is also written in the Wikipedia article. These SSI projects aggregate tightly coupled machines. They are not really suitable for general distributed environment like the one you've described. BOINC is way more appropriate and it also offers support for heterogeneous computing, e.g. 32- and 64-bit Windows and Linux machines can donate CPU power.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Investigate these projects [BOINC](http://boinc.berkeley.edu), [Condor](http://research.cs.wisc.edu/condor/)

Comment: Thanks a lot. BOINC is a possible solution. I'm setting up the virtual server to test it.....